# SELECT DISTINCT Inside WHERE IN clause performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a performance question about the following code...

```
SELECT*FROM GCL_Loans WHERE Loan_ID IN
(
    SELECT Loan_ID FROM GCL_Loan_Items
)
```

`GCL_Loans` has a list of loans with basic infomation
`CCL_Loan_Items` has information about a specific item in a loan. There can be duplicate Loan_ID's in `GCL_Loan_Items`

Can anyone explain why this query would be faster or slower than the one above?

```
SELECT*FROM GCL_Loans WHERE Loan_ID IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Loan_ID FROM GCL_Loan_Items
)
```

Comment: Is it faster or slower? What indexes are on GCL_Loans and GCL_Load_Items?

Comment: Check the execution plans. I strongly suspect they will be the same. See [Is using DISTINCT as a hint in subqueries useful?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/51430/3690)

Comment: I just tried this.  Table A has 1.2M rows.  Table B has 300K rows.  There was no time difference using DISTINCT.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith this is the exact same question I had!

Answer (score 1):

The "DISTINCT" version is probably faster, because the `IN` clause will have a smaller data set to search to determine if any given `GCL_Loans.Loan_ID` is in the set.  Without the `DISTINCT`, the data set will be larger.

There's a reasonably good argument to be made that the query optimizer will automatically recognize the `IN` test is a set-wise, not a list-wise test and do the DISTINCT during auto-indexing ... but I've seen that fail before.

Note that subselects can be a fail here too, because some databases (mysql) will execute the subselect for each element in the primary select.

Answer (score 0):

The plan and performance of both is equal

Answer (score -1):

Because by selecting DISTINCT there is less criteria in the SUBQuery (IN). 
My understanding is SQL will run the subquery first to generate the list of items that are to be included in the IN.

Comment: On the other hand, if there's very few duplicate records in the GCL_Loan_Items table, the added overhead of all the "is this possibly a duplicate" checking make actually make things worse.

Comment: What about the overhead of getting only distinct `Loan_ID`'s? Is that minimal compared to comparisons of the IN?

Comment: But essentially I said the same thing you said in a slightly different way: because the IN clause will have a smaller data set to search

Comment: SQL is declarative not imperative.